# Python recursive Merge Sort by index

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I have a question about the Python version of recursive Merge Sort. I completed the basic version, which is only referred by the array, and am now working on the index version. I will sink into the endless loop, but I am not sure where I did wrong. Would you mind sharing some ideas? Thank you in advance.

The successful and non-index version:

```
def mergesort(x):
    # The base case is when the array contains less than 1 observation. 
    length = len(x)
    if length < 2:
        return x
    else:
        # Recursive case:merge sort on the lower subarray, and the upper subarray. 
        mid = (length) // 2
        lower = mergesort(x[:mid])
        upper = mergesort(x[mid:])
        # merge two subarrays.
        x_sorted = merge(lower, upper)
        return (x_sorted)

def merge(lower, upper):
    nlower = len(lower)
    nupper = len(upper)
    i, j, k = 0, 0, 0
    # create a temp array to store the sorted results
    temp = [0] * (nlower + nupper)
    # as the lower and upper are sorted, since the base case is the single observation. 
    # now we compare the smallest element in each sorted array, and store the smaller one to the temp array
    # repeat this process until one array is completed moved to the temp array 
    # store the other array to the end of the temp array 
    while i < nlower and j < nupper:
        if lower[i] <= upper[j]:
            temp[k] = lower[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        else:
            temp[k] = upper[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1
    if i == nlower:
        temp[i+j:] = upper[j:]
    else:
        temp[i+j:] = lower[i:]
    return temp
```

With expected results:

```
x = random.sample(range(0, 30), 15)
mergesort(x)
[0, 1, 3, 6, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 17, 18, 20, 25, 27, 29]
```

But I will stuck into the endless loop with the index version:

```
def ms(x, left, right):
    # the base case: right == left as a single-element array
    if left < right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        ms(x, left, mid)
        ms(x, mid, right + 1)
        m(x, left, mid, right)
    return m
def m(x, left, mid, right):
    nlower = mid - left
    nupper = right - mid + 1
    temp = [0] * (nlower + nupper)
    ilower, iupper, k = left, mid, 0
    
    while ilower < mid and iupper < right + 1:
        if x[ilower] <= x[iupper]:
            temp[k] = x[ilower]
            ilower += 1
            k += 1
        else:
            temp[k] = x[iupper]
            iupper += 1
            k += 1
    if ilower == mid:
        temp[k:] = x[iupper:right+1]
    else:
        temp[k:] = x[ilower:mid]
    x[left:right+1] = temp
    return x
```

The test data as:

```
x = random.sample(range(0, 30), 15)
ms(x, 0, 14)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-39859c9eae4a> in <module>
      1 x = random.sample(range(0, 30), 15)
----> 2 ms(x, 0, 14)

... last 2 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-57-854342dcdefb> in ms(x, left, right)
      3     if left < right:
      4         mid = (left + right)//2
----> 5         ms(x, left, mid)
      6         ms(x, mid, right+1)
      7         m(x, left, mid, right)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Would you mind providing some insights? Thanks.

Comment: Look closely at the calculation and use of your midpoint. What happens if you're considering a two element list?

Comment: @HansMusgrave Thank you for your suggestion. I got a little bit confused about the 2-element list example. In this case, left=0 and right=1, mid=(0+1)//2=1, then ms(x, 0, 1) and ms(x, 1, 1) separately. I am not sure why this split will cause bugs? Would you mind providing any explanation? Thank you.

Comment: The accepted answer covered it pretty well, but walk through that example you gave just a step further. You call `ms(x, 0, 1)`, and that calls `ms(x, 0, 1)`, that calls `ms(x, 0, 1)`, that calls `ms(x, 0, 1)`, .... You're repeating the same function call forever without taking any action that might cause it to exit (hence the RecursionError -- that's often a telltale sign that one of your functions is calling itself in a transitive loop rather than falling back to its base cases)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, @HansMusgrave. I think I get it. The base case is that the left == right, however, in the ms(x, 0, 1), since it hasn't reach the base case, it will endless repeat calling this function. That is why I got the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index version uses a confusing convention whereby `left` is the index of the first element in the slice and `right` is the index of the last element. This convention requires error-prone `+1`/`-1` adjustments. Your problem is this: `mid` as computed is the index of the last element in the left half, but you consider `mid` to be the first element of the right half: a slice of 2 elements is split into one with 0 and one with 2, hence the infinite recursion. You can fix this problem by changing `ms(x, mid, right+1)` to `ms(x, mid+1, right)`, etc.

Furthermore, retuning `m` from function `ms` makes no sense. You should return `x` if anything at all.

It is much less error prone for `right` to be the index one past the last element, just like range specifiers in Python. This way there are no confusing `+1`/`-1` adjustments.

Here is modified version:

```py
def ms(x, left, right):
    # the base case: right - left as a single-element array
    if right - left >= 2:
        mid = (left + right) // 2  # index of the first element of the right half
        ms(x, left, mid)
        ms(x, mid, right)
        m(x, left, mid, right)
    return x

def m(x, left, mid, right):
    nlower = mid - left
    nupper = right - mid
    temp = [0] * (nlower + nupper)
    ilower, iupper, k = left, mid, 0
    
    while ilower < mid and iupper < right:
        if x[ilower] <= x[iupper]:
            temp[k] = x[ilower]
            ilower += 1
            k += 1
        else:
            temp[k] = x[iupper]
            iupper += 1
            k += 1
    if ilower == mid:
        temp[k:] = x[iupper:right]
    else:
        temp[k:] = x[ilower:mid]
    x[left:right] = temp
    return x
```

You would invoke as:

```
x = random.sample(range(0, 30), 15)
ms(x, 0, len(x))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @chqrlie. I got a little bit confused about the 2-element list example. In this case, left=0 and right=1, mid=(0+1)//2=1, then ms(x, 0, 1) and ms(x, 1, 1) separately. I am not sure why this split will cause bugs? Would you mind providing any explanation? Thank you.